# TOAD for Oracle - Autocomplete

Tags: oracle, toad

maybe it's a newbie question but I'm new in the Oracle world.
I'm working with TOAD for Oracle 9 and have 2 servers with Oracle 10g, when I connect to server A I can use te autocomplete feature of TOAD, but when I connect to server B the autocomplete does not appear.
The 2 servers have the same databases, A is for developement and B is for production.
I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that whatever schema you are connecting to on production lacks privileges on the system views that TOAD uses for autocomplete. Can you run this query on production, for instance:

`Select   column_name, data_type, column_id
    FROM SYS.user_tab_columns`

Answer (score 0):

That happens if you do not specify the schema. Likely on the test server you log in with the actual schema and on the production you have some read only user. So maybe you login on A with the user P and on the B with the user R. So you maybe have to type P.MYTABLE to get the autocomplete on B.

Comment: I'm trying what you say and still can't use the autocomplete